# Topology manager in load balanced scenario

Tags: web8, topology-manager

I'm upgrading from Tridion 2011 to Web 8. The current situation is like this: On production Live, we have 2 CD servers which are basically a copy of eachother. Both contain a deployer, broker database, file system for binaries and a website. Requests to the website are load balanced and in the publication target we have a destination for each server.

I am now trying to figure out how to set up topology manager for this scenario. The idea was to have a discovery service on each server, add 1 topology type and 2 `CdEnvironments` (1 for each server). But I don't understand how to create the `TtmWebsite`, as I can only enter 1 `CdEnvironmentId`. Do I have to add 2 websites (1 for each server)? If so, both use the same url (load balanced) and the PS scripts gives errors saying this `baseURL` already exists.

Is this scenario still supported or should we migrate to a single deployer/broker setup? Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

A scaled-out/load-balanced CD Environment should be modeled as a single `CdEnvironment` in Topology Manager.

You should not try to do something like mirroring on two separate CD Environments; multi-destination support was intentionally removed in SDL Web 8, because it doesn't really work.

High Availability of the Deployer can be achieved using an Active/Passive (fail-over) configuration.

Comment: Can you please provide details on setting active/Passive deployer and also how can we do load balancing for content service?

Comment: This is really down to just infrastructure; proper use and configuration of load balancers.

Comment: This setup was supported in 2011. Does your answer mean this cannot be done with Topology Manager?

Comment: The limitation is not in Topology Manager; Topology Manager models logical Environments and a scaled-out CD Environment is one logical Environment.

Comment: So the current way of infrastructure with 2 deployers and 2 broker databases is not supported anymore and cannot be configured with topology manager?

Comment: That is correct.